Using `openapi_examples` with `add_api_route` in FastAPI
I'm dynamically creating FastAPI endpoints like this:

class Endpoint(BaseSettings):
    model: Any
    name: str
    template: str


products: list[Any] = [
    Endpoint(
        model=a,
        name="a",
        template="a",
    ),
    Endpoint(
        model=b,
        name="b",
        template="b",
    ),
]


def create_endpoint(p: Endpoint, examples: Dict = None):
    async def endpoint(parameters: Any):
        logger.info(
            f"Request to {p.name} product",
            parameters=parameters.export(),
        )
        payload = preprocess(name=p.name, parameters=parameters.export())
        logger.info("payload", payload=payload.model_dump())
        return await submit_process(payload)

    return endpoint


for p in endpoints:
    router.add_api_route(
        f"/endpoints/{p.name}", create_endpoint(p), tags=["endpoint"], methods=["POST"]
    )

Now I'd also like to be able to add multiple examples using openapi-examples.
When I do look at the add_api_route function, I can't really find a corresponding argument.
Would appreciate any inputs (:

It was quite simple; I just had to add an Annotated type for the parameter like the resource I referenced in my question multiple-examples using openapi
from typing import Annotated

def create_endpoint(p: Product):
    async def endpoint(
        parameters: Annotated[
            p.model,
            Body(
                openapi_examples={
                    f"example_{i}": {
                        "summary": v[0],
                        "value": v[1],
                    }
                    for i, v in enumerate(p.examples.items())
                },
            )
            if p.examples
            else None,
        ],
    ):
        payload = preprocess(name=p.name, parameters=parameters.export())
        logger.info("payload", payload=payload.model_dump())
        return await submit_process(payload)

    return endpoint


If your endpoints are this regular, they are in fact one endpoint, and your life will probably be easier if you use FastAPI the "intended" way:
from typing import Literal

ProductName = Literal["a", "b"]

models: dict[ProductName, Any] = {"a": a, "b": b}
templates: dict[ProductName, str] = {"a": "a", "b": "b"}

@router.post("/endpoints/{name}")
async def endpoint(name: ProductName):
    # Your endpoint code here, where you can use Pydantic models for the body

Then you can use openapi_examples just like you normally would.

Thank you! I did solve it and added my own answer (:
